# How to sign-in? Django TastyPie with ApiKeyAuthentication actual authentication Process

Tags: django, authentication, tastypie

I have an Adobe Air mobile application that communicates with Django via TastyPie. To use the app people have to register first. Therefore they have to supply their email and password. Afterwards they will be able to "login". I thought it would be the best idea that after entering a successful username/password combination, the api-key will be sent back to the mobile app where it will be cached, so the user is "logged in".

Please tell me if you think there is a better way for registering and "logging in" users.

Inside Django I have a UserRessource class that I use to register new users when sending data via POST:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'auth'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        fields = ['username', 'email']

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        username, email, password = bundle.data['username'], bundle.data['password'], bundle.data['password'], 
        try:
            bundle.obj = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise BadRequest('That username already exists')
        return bundle
```

That works very well.

But now I'm struggling with the actual login process. In my opinion it would be best to send username and password via GET (and https) to this ressource and if those are valid, return the users api key. But would that be possible? And is it clean? Usually TastyPie would show all users currently in the DB if you send a GET request to that ressource. But I dont need that data, so I could overwrite that somehow. I already checked http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.9/resources.html but I don't get it to work. Is it even possible to overwrite that behaviour?

So the actual questions are **Whats the best way to "sign in" a user using ApiKeyAuthentication?**
And **Is my approach right and clean or do you have a better method?** and **Do you have any examples for this case?**

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using BasicAuth so it may be slightly different. But my solution is basicaly an empty resource that requires authentication. If the authentication is a success the service returns response code 200 and the authenticated user, I override obj_get_list and stuff the authenticated user in there. If the credentials are wrong the service returns response code 401.

```
 class LoginResource(ModelResource):
        class Meta:
            allowed_methods = ['get']
            resource_name = 'login'
            include_resource_uri = False
            object_class = User
            authentication = BasicAuthentication()
            authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

        def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
            return [bundle.request.user]
```

Comment: I would suggest adding `excludes = ['password']` to Meta to prevent the password hashes to be transported over the api.

Comment: The idea of a GET request on an empty resource is clever! Otherwise, if you want to make a GET on a userResource, you have to know the user id, which is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I'll try to explain my point of view on the topic:
First the UserResource example on the tastypie page for me has one significant issue:
The User Objects should not be presented at any time to the single User, they should be able to see they're own "profile" or whatever but never browse and see others. Of course that can be done and with UserResource by clearing the main "list view" of that resource and applying the APIKeyAuth to the individual profiles, but still I don't like the idea of UserResource.
Second in the form when you are developing an API(such as tastypie usage) the APIKey is the actual "password" so what should be send on request is not the username and password but the username and APIKey, which is obtained in other manners(normally an e-mail or some kind of website based UI). Than they are recommended to be send via Authorization Header and not in GET parameters.
Third when we are talking about API there is no such thing as sign-in - at least not in the RESTFULL APIs - it is in some sense connectionless, so you actually going to send the Authorization header with each request. 
As to the question yes you can overwrite the data. Look at the hydrate/dehydrate cycle in the Tastypie docs to understand how does it renders the content and if you have more question go ahead and ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Belov! You are exactly right. Later I want to further restrict or block the detail view, so nobody can lookup all my users. Clearing the main "list view" and clearing the "detai view" is necessary. So in the end it wouldn't be a real TastyPie Ressource anymore because most functions will be blocked and GET will be used for login and POST will be used for registering. Your second and third point about "sign in" is clear to me, I try to specify my problem in my question.

Comment: Okay so 2 points here than: 1. If you want to restrict people from seeing anything on the list_view overwrite "get_object_list" to return nothing. 2.To use the ApiKeyAuth you need to add it to the model (instead of Authorization()) and an example call to the API via ajax for example would be:$.ajax({type: 'GET',url: '/api/v0/bundle/1/',data: None,contentType: 'application/json', beforeSend: function(req) { req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);},}); And sorry but can't format a comment properly.

Comment: Oh and where auth="ApiKey: username:apikey".

Comment: Belov, thanks. And sorry for not specifing my question better. My main problem is that I dont know whats the best way to exchange a username/password combination for an api-key which will be cached in the frontend then. I added some more explanation to my question.

Comment: Normally, as far as I know and I think google API and twitter's too do this, is you have an web Interface like a website where the person loges in to some basic account. And there is a page where he can "generate" an api-key, which he can than use by copy/pasting it. https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys

Comment: @Belov could you explain why it's recommended to be send via Authorization Header and not in GET parameters? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, in general you are not required to send via the header, but it is so to say good practice, and if you intend your serve side to be used by third party custom applications they would probably use that as it is the HTTP protocol standard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header